# Python c api, подскажите название метода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно взять адрес объекта в памяти при помощи `C API`, это тот что в Python возвращает функция `id`. Понятно что я могу сделать так `&(*obj)`, но метод такой в `api` то где то есть, ищу не могу найти, подскажите название.

Comment: А можете рассказать зачем это? Возможно, вам ctypes поможет

Comment: ctypes мне точно не поможет ) Хочу свою библиотеку по работе с многомерными тензорами написаную на `c` в python засунуть.